# Timeseries with Min/Max for three series as a function of Location and toggle to change plot based on Location

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some test data that I need to do some simple analysis. I have to calculate yearly min, mean and max for three different benchmarks (Level 1, 2 and 3) as a function of location (from 2020 to 2050).

[Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJyKH.png)

Now that I have the summary statistics done, I need do the following:

1. Create a timeseries plot with min/max shading for all three benchmarks per location (see example below)
   [min/max example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhtTu.png)
2. Find a way to either create this plot for each of the locations, or implement some sort of button that would allow me to toggle between locations

Data is here:
[Test.csv](https://gist.github.com/MGCK23/8bb2280553add20d7e4566dd9974a6b2)

So far I have had good success with the summary statistics. Below is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ETMF = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
ETMF['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(ETMF['Date']).year
ETMF = ETMF[['Date','Year','Location','Level 1','Level 2','Level 3']]
ETMF.drop('Date',axis=1,inplace = True)
data = pd.melt(ETMF, id_vars=['Year','Location'],var_name='Benchmark',value_name='Value').groupby(['Year','Location','Benchmark'])['Value'].agg(['min','mean','max'])
data
```

I have tried isolating the data to just one location but I haven't been able to get much progress on the plot, let alone the dropdown/button option to toggle or print them all (I am still learning Python so please be kind).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!